# Мой шофер отвезет тебя куда скажешь

Tags: синтаксис

Исправьте меня, пожалуйста!

Надо определить тип предложения + что такое "*куда скажешь*".

> *Мой шофер отвезет тебя **куда скажешь**.*

Определила это предложение как главное. 
"Куда скажешь": обстоятельство места (выражено наречием *куда* + спрягаемым глаголом). Правильно так?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мой шофер отвезет тебя куда скажешь.**

Это простое предложение, распространенное определением *мой*, дополнением *тебя* и обстоятельством места *куда скажешь*.

Но обстоятельство места выражено **цельным словосочетанием** "куда скажешь", которое имеет структуру **придаточного неполного предложения.**

Эти варианты надо различать, например: Сегодня мы поедем, куда скажешь. Это придаточное предложение (делается пауза, ставится запятая).

Тема у Розенталя: [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

Comment: Можно было бы согласиться с отсутствием придаточного предложения в варианте "отвезёт... куда угодно" (фразеологизм со значением "в любое место" - обстоятельство), но здесь конкретный смысл "туда, куда ты скажешь", как и в вашем примере с запятой.

Comment: Структура предложений разная, поэтому иногда удобно сделать паузу, а иногда нет. В заданном предложении пауза явно отсутствует.  А Вы, Alex_ander, как я догадываюсь, предпочитаете семантические решения, не правда ли?

Comment: К сожалению, пунктуация часто противоречит естественной расстановке пауз (напр. когда запятая оказывается после союза "и"); правилами она больше привязана к грамматическим конструкциям, на которые и приходится ориентироваться (иногда - выявляя их через смысл).

Comment: Интонация не противоречива, просто ее возможности ограничены, поэтому она всегда выражает старшую конструкцию, например отношения между частями сложного предложения, а  обособленный оборот, отнесенный к одному предложению,  не всегда можно обозначить. В этом случае мы ориентируемся только на грамматический принцип. В то же время в остальных случаях интонация   помощник незаменимый. Кстати, в правилах Розенталя часто упоминаются интонационные решения, не в пример современной редакции Лопатина.